# How can I do to plot an hist

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

Hello I have some dates and I am trying to plot an hist. I mean I have some dates and I want an hist which shows the frequency monthly. Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dateslist = ["25/07/2019", "25/07/2019", 
"25/07/2019", "26/07/2019", "29/07/2019", 
"29/07/2019", "30/07/2019", "18/08/2019",  
"18/08/2019", "20/08/2019", "20/08/2019", 
"21/08/2019", "21/08/2019", "22/08/2019", 
"27/08/2019", "23/09/2019", "26/09/2019", 
"27/09/2019", "30/09/2019", "09/10/2019", 
"18/10/2019", "18/10/2019", "18/10/2019", 
"18/10/2019", "29/10/2019", "29/10/2019", 
"21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", 
"21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", 
"21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", 
"21/11/2019", "29/11/2019", "06/12/2019", 
"11/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "18/12/2019", 
"23/12/2019", "23/12/2019", "23/12/2019", 
"24/12/2019", "24/12/2019", "23/01/2020", 
"20/01/2020", "20/01/2020", "20/01/2020", 
"19/02/2020", "31/01/2020", "24/02/2020", 
"25/02/2020", "25/02/2020", "02/03/2020", 
"18/03/2020", "19/03/2020", "23/03/2020", 
"02/04/2020", "14/04/2020", "21/04/2020", 
"24/04/2020", "20/05/2020"]

dateslistconverted = []

for datelist in dateslist:
    if datetime.strptime(datelist, "%d/%m/%Y").month in range(1,6):
        dateslistconverted.append(datetime.strptime(datelist, "%d/%m/%Y").month+12)
    else: 
        dateslistconverted.append(datetime.strptime(datelist, "%d/%m/%Y").month)

plt.hist(dateslistconverted)
plt.show()
```

But I have no the good format I would like to have the date ordered by time and with some spaces between the different months.

How could I do ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas as it handles datetimes quite nicely and also you can plot it directly:

```
pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(dateslist)).apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m")).value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```

Here I just converted you list to datetime format and wrapped it into a Series so I can adjust the date format. Then I count each month value, sort it and plot it.

```
import pandas as pd

dateslist = ["25/07/2019", "25/07/2019", 
"25/07/2019", "26/07/2019", "29/07/2019", 
"29/07/2019", "30/07/2019", "18/08/2019",  
"18/08/2019", "20/08/2019", "20/08/2019", 
"21/08/2019", "21/08/2019", "22/08/2019", 
"27/08/2019", "23/09/2019", "26/09/2019", 
"27/09/2019", "30/09/2019", "09/10/2019", 
"18/10/2019", "18/10/2019", "18/10/2019", 
"18/10/2019", "29/10/2019", "29/10/2019", 
"21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", 
"21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", 
"21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", "21/11/2019", 
"21/11/2019", "29/11/2019", "06/12/2019", 
"11/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "18/12/2019", 
"23/12/2019", "23/12/2019", "23/12/2019", 
"24/12/2019", "24/12/2019", "23/01/2020", 
"20/01/2020", "20/01/2020", "20/01/2020", 
"19/02/2020", "31/01/2020", "24/02/2020", 
"25/02/2020", "25/02/2020", "02/03/2020", 
"18/03/2020", "19/03/2020", "23/03/2020", 
"02/04/2020", "14/04/2020", "21/04/2020", 
"24/04/2020", "20/05/2020"]

pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(dateslist)).apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m")).value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar');
```

---

[image]